# How can I use php's built in http server + mysql?

Tags: php, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to connect to mysql server using the following code:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");

if(!$connection)
{
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}
```

And I'm getting "`Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`". Why is that? isn't this function built in in php?

I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04 + php 5.4.11` + php's built in http server.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: PHP and mysql server built in *what*?

Comment: You need to install mysql extension to use mysql features apart from only PHP

Comment: Note on the first comment: not "PDO or MySQLi" but just PDO. Mysqli is unusable with prepared statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First do not use mysql_* functions as those functions are deprecated

and second you need to install php5-mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

and then you can use mysqli and also PDO (needs to be installed too).

Comment: did you restart your apache server `sudo service apache2 restart` ?

Comment: Sorry, the current exception is  "Call to undefined function   die()". I'm not using apache, I'm using php's built in http server. @Boynux

Comment: Use exit not die and print your message using print/echo.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the extension.

Be aware that this API is deprecated.